# What controls the print queue expiry timeout?

Tags: printing

If my printer is turned off, `lpr` still works fine, `lpq` shows the job in the print queue, and if I turn on the printer the job prints okay.

But if I wait a few hours though, `lpr` shows that the queue is empty and my print job has disappeared, so obviously something is automatically deleting old print jobs.

What controls that automated deletion, and how can I configure it to wait longer?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/834481/how-to-prevent-cups-from-timing-out-jobs  Set the `MaxJobTime` in the `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` file.

Comment: @Terrance, I'd mark this a "best answer", but it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/834482/440143) all you should have to do is to add a line like the following to your `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`:

```
MaxJobTime 0
```

`0` means disabled timeout.  Default is `10800` seconds which is 3 hours if not specified.

Example:

If you want 5 hours you put the time in as seconds:

```
MaxJobTime 18000
```

You can play around with the seconds and find what suits your needs.

Hope this helps!